# Pass and print a $_GET variable through an included file

Tags: php, variables

I have a php file 
index.php and its url is `index.php?var=item`
I defined get variable in `index.php`

in index.php

```
<?php
    require "included.php";
    $var=$_GET['var'];
?>
```

I echoed this variable in my `included.php` like below

in included.php

```
<?php
    echo $var;
?>
```

When I launch `index.php?var=item`, its shows an error that var is not defined in `included.php`?

How to overcome this? I want to define some variables in `index.php` from url and do some staff in included file.

Comment: You need to set the `$var` before including the file.

Comment: I don't know why this question gets downvoted. it's a beginner question - but that's not a reason to downvote it.

Answer (score 0):

like Joachim Martinsen posted as a comment (I don't know why he hasn't just answered), you have to set the `$var` before including your file:

```
<?php
    $var=$_GET['var'];
    require "included.php";
?>
```

inlcuding in PHP basically just works like concatenating one file out of other files. so your original code would result in:

```
<?php
    echo $var;
    $var=$_GET['var']; 
?>
```

which obviously doesn't work because the variable is echoed before it is getting a value assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Any variables set up in your PHP code before including another file would work there. The included file won't be aware of any other variable that was declared or set after it was included.

In `index.php`, do this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['var'])) {
        $var=$_GET['var'];
    }
    require "included.php";
?>
```

Then access the `$var` value like you are already trying to do in `included.php`.

And as I am writing this answer, I can see that a similar answer has just been posted. Sorry for posting it anyway, I think it includes a bit more explanation.