# Pass and print a $_GET variable through php load file by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, load

I searched for a solution of passing a get variable obtained from index.php page to included.php file[ loaded by javascript ]. A nice solution by php require function is given [Pass and print a $_GET variable through an included file by php require function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32473781/pass-and-print-a-get-variable-through-an-included-file)

However, in my case I have

```html
for index.php => url[ index.php?var=item]
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['var'])) {
    $var=$_GET['var'];
    }
    ?>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#ok").load("included.php");
    });
    </script>

    <div id='ok'>

    </div>
```

```
 in included.php [which will be loaded in index.php by javascript load function]
 <?php
 echo $var;
 ?>
```

The error was the undefined var in included.php file.How Can I echo this variable with a combination of php and javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass these variables on to the included file you could go with

```
   $("#ok").load("included.php?<?php echo $urlString; ?>");
```

The URL string can be generated with this function

```
function GenGetVars(){
    $Base = NULL;
    foreach($_GET as $key => $variable){
        $Base .= '&'.$key.'='.$variable;
    }
    return(rtrim($Base, '&'));
}
```

Another option would be :

```
$( "#ok" ).load( "included.php", { "choices[]": [ "Jon", "Susan" ] } );
```

Based upon the first example:

**index.php:**

```
<?php
function GenGetVars(){
    $Base = NULL;
    foreach($_GET as $key => $variable){
        $Base .= '&'.$key.'='.$variable;
    }
    return(rtrim($Base, '&'));
}

if(isset($_GET['var']) === true) {
    $var=$_GET['var'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#ok").load("included.php?<?php echo GenGetVars(); ?>");
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='ok'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**included.php**

```
 <?php
 echo print_r($_GET, true);
 ?>
```

Comment: It seems your answer earns for multiple variable, I really feel interested.Brother, Can you explain little  more, better with an example? I guess you understand my poor level.

Comment: Brother, I understand something, I used  $("#ok").load("included.php?var=<?php echo $var;?>"); in the index.php. Originnaly, the javascript was in external .js file. It seems if I keep the javascript in index.php, it works fine. But How to work keeping script in external file? please little more help......!!!

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation with a fantastic example. I would be very please, If you would be kind to reply one more about the possibility of using javascript in an external .js file and how?

Comment: In general you cannot load any javascript files within a file that gets included by Javascript.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. But Keeping everything same, I just wanted javascript to save inside an external file like function.js and add this file into index.php by <script src="function.js"></script>. finally I would have three file. (1).index.php, (2).included.php and (3). function.js

Comment: You mean like the PHP counterpart : 

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
echo file_get_contents('file1.js');
echo file_get_contents('file2.js');
?>

?
</script>

Comment: No brother, I wanted to copy and past  $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#ok").load("included.php?<?php echo GenGetVars(); ?>");
    }); to a js file and include that js file in index.php inside head tag.

Comment: Well that's just something like : 'myjq.init.js'

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#ok").load("included.php?<?php echo GenGetVars(); ?>");
    });

And <script type="text/javascript" src="myjq.init.js"></script>

Comment: I am pretty happy with your patient. Unfortunately, it is not working, is that because of the file "myjq.init.js" is a JS file and it contained php tag[?<?php echo GenGetVars(); ?> ]? OR what?

Answer (score 0):

**index.php:**

```
<?php
function GenGetVars(){
    $Base = NULL;
    foreach($_GET as $key => $variable){
        $Base .= '&'.$key.'='.$variable;
    }
    return(rtrim($Base, '&'));
}

if(isset($_GET['var']) === true) {
    $var=$_GET['var'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadScriptFile(){
        /// SENDING THE INFORMATION BY AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",                  /// SEND TYPE
            url  : "getScriptName.php",     /// TARGET FILE TO RETRIEVE INFORMATION
            data : { 
                    'SomeParamID'                   : 1,
                    'AnotherParamID'                : 'Dunno.. just something'
                   },
                    ///######## IN CASE OF SUCCESS
                    success:function(response){
                    if( response != "" ){
                        $.getScript( 'js/' + response + '.js', function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
                          console.log( data ); // Data returned
                          console.log( textStatus ); // Success
                          console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
                          console.log( "Load was performed." );
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        alert( "Error retreiving data" );
                    }
               }
            }
        );  
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#ok").load("included.php?<?php echo GenGetVars(); ?>");
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='ok'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**included.php**

```
 <?php
 echo print_r($_GET, true);
 ?>
```

**getScriptName.php**

```
 <?php
 switch($_POST['SomeParamID']){
    case 1:
        echo 'MyGreatJSFile';
    break;
    case 2:
        echo 'MyNotSoGreatJSFile';
    break;
 }
 ?>
```

You could try this.